# Product version number in swift code

Tags: xcode, swift, build

Is there's a way to get the product version number inside swift code, like

```
println("Running version \($PRODUCT_VERSION)")
```

I have to define some standartUserDefaults, that are bound to the Version and build number and i don't like to put them into my code when it's there at build time.

NSProcessInfo don't have the build number. 
Any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Swift 5.3:

```
extension UIApplication {

 static var appVersion: String? {
    return Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as? String
 }

}
```

Usage:

```
UIApplication.appVersion!
```

Answer (score 7):

**SWIFT 4.2**

```
let appVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
let build = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String
let buildString = "Version: \(appVersion ?? "").\(build ?? "")"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get such info from your `Info.plist` through this:

```
let version = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?[kCFBundleVersionKey]
let build = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"]
println(version)  // product version
println(build)   //product build
```